# ActiveMQ converting `/` to `.` in queue names when using curl

Tags: activemq-classic

My 5.0.8 ActiveMQ queue is named `queue/andburn`. Using

```
curl -u admin:admin -d 'body="Aardvark"' "http://localhost:8161/api/message/queue/andburn?type=queue"
```

creates a new queue `queue.andburn`.  When I escape `/` like `\/` I get `queue\.andburn`.  When I omit `type=queue` I don't see my message added to my existing queue.  Same when I use `&#47;` to represent slashes.

Note: all escaping was done after `queue` in the URI, e.g.

```
"http://localhost:8161/api/message/queue\/andburn?type=queue"
```

The [ActiveMQ REST page](http://activemq.apache.org/rest.html) was not helpful in addressing this.

Here is the output of `curl --version`

```
curl 7.24.0 (x86_64-apple-darwin12.0) libcurl/7.24.0 OpenSSL/0.9.8y zlib/1.2.5
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps ldap ldaps pop3 pop3s rtsp smtp smtps telnet tftp
Features: AsynchDNS GSS-Negotiate IPv6 Largefile NTLM NTLM_WB SSL libz
```

*Update*: This is also happening when sending requests to ActiveMQ via a Ruby script using the RestClient gem.

Comment: Created ActiveMQ issue [AMQ-4756](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AMQ-4756)

Comment: [AMQ-4756](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AMQ-4756) appears to have been fixed now -- thanks ActiveMQ community!

Answer (score 0):

Escaping URLs is typically done by [percent encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding). So in your case a slash would be %2F

```
http://localhost:8161/api/message/queue%2Fandburn?type=queue
```

I have not tested this with CURL and ActiveMQ, but it's the most natural way to represent a slash in a URI.

Comment: This also results in a queue named `queue.andburn`.  It is as if the URI is decoded, then all of thw `/`s are converted to `.`s.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this issue today and did a minor search. I use ActiveMQ version 5.15.11. The solution that worked for me can be found [here](https://activemq.apache.org/rest). I simply used the alternate producing syntax. Simply, http://127.0.0.1:8161/api/message?type=queue&destination=My.Queue.With/Slash (instead of giving the queue name after ../message.queue/{queue_name})